# How to create a form that uses data from multiple lines?

Tags: php, html, forms

First of all, I'm aware that the title is not very clear, it's because I'm having trouble put the issue I have into words, so if anyone understands what I'm about to describe, please suggest a new title for me to edit.

Now for the main problem, I will do my best to explain it :

The user ( a teacher ) logs in, he then chooses one of the classes he teaches, the website displays a list of the students that are in that class as a table.

the table contains 3 columns : Name , lastName, Present.

Present is a column containing 2 radio buttons : Absent & Present.
I want the teacher to choose one of them for every student, then press "Submit".

The submit will result in the insertion of data into a table that contains the ID of the student that was absent, the current date, and the ID of the class. Here is the code for showing the table :

```
    <?php if (isset($_GET['choice'])) {
            $choice = $_GET['choice'];
            $showquery = $conn->prepare('select Nom,Prenom,etudiant_ID from etudiant where classe_id = (select classe_id from classe where abreviation= ?)');
            $showquery->execute(array($choice));


            echo $choice;
            echo ("<form>");
            echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prenom</th>
    <th> Presence</th>
    </tr>";
            while ($row = $showquery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $counter = $row['etudiant_ID'];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Nom'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Prenom'] . "</td>"; ?>
                <td> Present <input type="radio" name="presence<?=$counter?>" value='present' checked>
                           Absent <input type="radio" name="presence<?=$counter?>" value="absent">
                           </td>
                <?php
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
echo ("<input name='matiere' placeholder='matiere..' required > ");
            echo ("<form>");
        } ?>


    </main>
```

Here is an image that could help you better understand :
[The table that is inside the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYxLj.png)

Comment: What you're doing seems clear enough. What is the problem you're having, exactly? The only thing I can see offhand is that you included no submit element.

Comment: @DonR I had no idea how to handle the form in another page, because the amount of radio boxes is variable, I did fix it now by using some weird dark magic